# KVO on NSStatusItem.isVisible fires twice

Tags: swift, appkit, key-value-observing, nsstatusitem

I'm trying to use key value observation to determine when an `NSStatusItem` is dragged out of the menu bar by the user with the `removalAllowed` behavior. This is supported according to the docs:

> Status items with this behavior allow interactive removal from the menu bar. Upon removal, the item’s isVisible property changes to false. **This change is observable using key-value observation.**

However, the callback function seems to fire twice whenever the `isVisible` property is changed. Here's a minimal example (assume `statusItem` and `observer` are variables that are retained for the lifetime of the app, e.g. on `AppDelegate`).

```
statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)
statusItem.button!.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.addTemplateName)
statusItem.behavior = .removalAllowed

observer = statusItem.observe(\.isVisible, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
    print("oldValue: \(change.oldValue!) newValue: \(change.newValue!)")
}
```

If you drag the icon out of the menu bar, it will print the following:

```
oldValue: false newValue: true
oldValue: false newValue: true
```

I've looked through every property on the `change` object and as far as I can tell, they're all identical, so there'd be no easy way to discard the duplicate event. I've also messed with the `prior` option, which doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart way to get rid of duplicates is to replace the KVO observer with a Combine publisher.

```
import Combine

var cancellable : AnyCancellable?

cancellable = statusItem.publisher(for: \.isVisible)
    .removeDuplicates()
    .sink { value in
        print(value)
    }
```

If you are interested in the old value you could add the `Scan` operator

Comment: Excellent workaround, thanks